# Windows 7 Software Installation : Siemens Step7 and Siemens SCL

Tags: windows-7, installation

We use Siemens Step7 and SCL for PLC programming in our company.

I recently got to install Windows 7 and had yet to find out that the Siemens software suite doesn't install anymore. - Which is a pain...

Checking through the setup files, I found following entries in the Setups.ini file:

```
[OS]
PlattformIDAllowed=1;2
WinXP=True
WinXPExclude=0,Home,1
WinXPWarning=1
WinNETServer=True
WinNETServerExclude=Home,0,1
WinNETServerWarning=Home,0,1
Win2003=1
Win2003Exclude=Home,0,1
Win2003Warning=Home,0,1
Win2003R2=1
Win2003R2Exclude=0,1
Win2003R2Warning=0,1
WinVista=1
Win2008=1
Win7=1
```

I added the last line to try things out and it still provides me the same error..

As far as I know the suite is installed by Install**Shield**.

All help would be very appreciated!

Comment: What exact error message do you get?

Comment: This is what I get: http://img523.imageshack.us/i/siemensinstallerror.png/

Comment: Try posting to controlsoverload.com  Siemens users there and may assist

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it in Windows Vista compatibility mode (right-click on installer and go on compatibility tab). Since this program does support Vista, I would expect that to work. Only installer is broken.

Comment: That didn't work. I still think I don't have the appropriate INI file settings, got any other idea?

Comment: Ini settings will not help since Win7=1 cannot be recognized by installer that doesn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed STEP7 with instructions described in this article:
http://xuek.ru/eblog/2009/10/step7-at-win7/

It works not in virtual machine and windows compatible mode don't work properly.
You must edit the setup.msi files. Setup.ini, probably, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed by using ORCA editing the msi file, but I cannot get on line as the PG-PC interface program says there is a dll missing. OK for editing offline though.
Have also installed on XP mode virtual machine, this works but is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed STEP7 on Windows-7 using the virtual XP.  I have allocated 2gig of ram for the virtual machine and the program runs well.  I can connect to machines remotely with cisco VPN and, the update has slight pauses, but is still stable.  The default amount of ram that the Virtual Machine allocates is only 512MB.  This is not really enough to run XP comfortably. Hope this helps.